# On The "Heterodox" Sampradayas

Tags: shaivism, sects, sampradaya

Namaskarah!

Regarding Shaivism, as far as I'm aware with the resources I've, the philosophy of mainstream Shaivite sampradayas such as Vira Shaivism, Shaiva Siddantha, Pasupatha Shaivism, Kashmiri Shaivism & Shaktism have been appropriately exposed & described in the great detail, especially in Jadunath Sinha's book.

But, it seems more Tantric & heterodox sects such as Kaula, Kapalika, Kalamukha, & Kubjika haven't been discussed, or exposed in the same great detail. So far as I'm aware, those sects are also philosophically monistic **(correct me if I'm wrong)**. But I've several questions:

1. What are the differences in practice between Kaula, Kapalika, Kalamukha, & Kubjika Sampradayas?
2. Is it true that:

- Natha Sampradaya is an offshoot from Kaula Sampradaya?
- Aghori Sampradaya is an offshoot from Kapalika Sampradaya?
- Vira Shaivism is an offshoot from Kalamukha Sampradaya?

3. What did mainstream Shaivite acharyas think on those four heterodox sects?

Comment: This idea of 'orthodox' and 'heterodox' is quite colonial and non-Indic in nature.